# Is it OK to let a function initialise a variable, via passing the variable as an argument by reference?

Tags: php

I noticed that it does not appear necessary to initialise a variable to zero when passing it as an argument by reference.  For example:

```
function foo($nm, &$var) {
    $var++;
    echo "Something about ".$nm.": ".$var;
}
$bar = 0; // <- this line is redundant
foo("bar", $bar);
echo "<br>";
foo("baz", $baz); // <- works just fine
```

Whilst explicitly initialising a variable like "bar" is more readable, less is more IMO, so I prefer the "baz" style of coding.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: In the title: "Is it OK...?"

Comment: Well it works, but I personally would still initialize it, because as soon as you , for example, try to decrement it, it will fail. What is happening here is that the variable, since it is passed by reference, it will get [created and assigned with NULL](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign). After that [incrementing NULL will work and returns 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Comment: Oh, I just tried decrementing baz at the end and it went back to zero.  So I don't know what you mean when you say it will fail.

Comment: Just decrement it, don't increment it first.

Comment: Well I don't want to decrement it.  Rizier123 what on earth are you commenting about?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean if the first mention is "$baz--;" then there is an error, but there again I'm not doing that in my code so does it matter?

Comment: As I said it works, but as I also said I would initialize it for consistence and so that it is clearer what you do.